# Is Docker capable of providing container with gigabit network?

Tags: networking, docker

I [tried to setup a docker environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739331/how-to-improve-docker-low-network-speed-bridged-network) with gigabit network speed. My docker host is capable and nativly running services with 1000mbps.

Is it even possible to enable my docker container to use gigabit network speed and avoid the fastethernet (100mbps) connection? If so, can anyone give my a **hint** how to do that or a working **How to...**

I read and reread the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) multiple times, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Cross-posting isn't really appreciated: http://askubuntu.com/questions/739331/how-to-improve-docker-low-network-speed-bridged-network

Comment: is it cross-posting? I changed the focus, title and content of the question. If it is still, I'll remove my other question, because if this question is not answered, the earlier question is obsolet.